# .Map reactjs no puedo acceder a los datos

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hola buenas tengo el siguiente error al acceder alos datos con .map estoy usando Context

```
 const [ViewDatos,setViewDatos] = useState([])

 useEffect(()=>{

      let data = new FormData();
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
      let config = {
          method: 'get',  
          maxBodyLength: Infinity,
          url: 'http://34.176.175.133:3000/users/requests',
          headers: { 
            'x-token': token, 
          //   ...data.getHeaders()
          },
          data : data
        };
        
        axios.request(config)
        .then((response) => {
          setViewDatos(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });   

     },[])

      const {ViewDatos} = useHydrodynamic()
      console.log(ViewDatos) //Me Lee Los datos hasta este momento 

   {ViewDatos.map((data)=>(
                  <p>{data.user}</p>
            ))}//AQUI SALE EL ERROR NO PUEDO ACCEDER A LOS DATOS
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por lo que se ve en consola, ViewDatos esta devolviendo un objeto y lo que necesitas para poder realizar un map es un array.

Comment: pregunta antes de mostrar los datos, si existe ViewDatos, con este condicional : { ViewDatos &&  ViewDatos.map((data)=>(
                  <p>{data.user}</p>) }